# SMTP Server in a cloud function, possible?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I would like to have a cloud (serverless) function which would accept requests as an email, I would then like to parse the title and body and store the data into a database.

I have looked into [Haraka](https://haraka.github.io/), and it feels like overkill - plus I am not sure if it would work as a serverless function.

Is this as simple as creating an MX record to on my domain to point to a cloud HTTP endpoint - and then parse the incoming email data in my function?

Comment: No; it’s not as simple as that. SMTP is separate from HTTP. You need something that can act like an SMTP server would, with `HELO` and all. I don’t think achieving this in a serverless model is realistic.

Comment: AWS lets you receive messages in something resembling the fashion you are proposing via their SES offering. There is a significant amount of nontrivial infrastructure between your MX record and the function you get to run when a message comes in, but then at least you don't have to understand or worry about that yourself.

Comment: Thank you @TZHX - I found this link which makes it look quite simple: https://gist.github.com/kennethkalmer/278814

Comment: Not serverless, but there are many good how-tos on setting up `postfix` - once that is done, you can tell postfix to run a script once mail is arrived - see this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178396/run-script-on-receipt-of-email/179256#179256  FWIW I did similar forever ago (like 2001ish) to create an archive of an email list that was basically 30 people using BCC ...